# CSS/JS - Responsive Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a responsive search box, similar to the one at http://www.hightimes.com/.

This search box input field will be hidden when the window size is <= 420px. And is triggered to be opened when the serach icon is clicked.

Have tried to decrypt the javascript code on the page, I have also tried to find an similar tutorial, but all I could find was this one: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingSearchBar/
It's not really the same.

Glad if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS write:

```
@media-screen and (max-width: 420px){
  .search-box {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

If you are using JQuery write:

```
if($(window).width()<420){
  $('.search-icon').click(function() {
    $('.search-box').toggleClass('input-visible');
  });
}
```

The input-visible class should have display: block or inline-block, with other desired styles, like position, size etc. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use css [@media_query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), detect if screen max-width is 420px then hide the textbox like .textbox{ display:none } inside the media query only.

use javascript to attach event handler on button onclick to hide and show the textbox.

put textbox default style outside the media_query so the styles will take effect only when screen size is <= 420.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the width of the windows. If you use jQuery, it will be very easy.
Give an ID to your search field and use jQuery to show / hide it. For example :

```js
// in your js
if ($(window).width() < 420) {
   $("#searchField").hide("fast");
}
else {
   $("#searchField").show("fast");
}
```

```html
    <!-- in your template -->
<input id="searchField" type="search" />
```